# Installing ubuntu 14 LTS : keyboard and mouse do not function

Tags: 14.04, mouse

i wanted to try ubuntu 14 but when i try to install it on my laptop which is lenovo a10-30, mouse and keyboard do not fucntion
i know that many had the same problem, but i can't reach to terminal in that case 
please if anybody  can tell me how to enable my mouse and keyboard while installing the system, it would be great.
thanks in advance.